# Paul Irish's Infinite Scroll Plugin with Ajax Jsonp

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

I am planning to use Paul Irish's Infinite Scroll Plugin , this gives the page numbers at the bottom as 1 , 2 , 3. But I want to load the data on ajax json request. Because i don't have the URL structure like that for paginations. I am using ajax for the same.

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/

May I know if anyone used this plugin with ajax and jsop request , if so please give me some directions on how to do.

One more thing is , nobody will have 2 ,3 ,4 , 5 pages pre-defined right , we can define some regex rules which can be resolved to some pages

Thanks.